# wait and collect multiple items at each timestamp from simpy.Store.get()

Tags: python, simpy

I am simulating a situation where 1->N number of orders of different types can arrive at each timestamp.

The simpy code:

```
import simpy
from dataclasses import dataclass
import random

@dataclass
class Order():
    id: int
    type: str

class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, env: simpy.Environment, seed: int):
        self.env = env
        self.order_id = 0
        self.orders_cache = simpy.Store(self.env, capacity=100)
        random.seed(seed)

    def generate_order(self, type: str):
        while True:
            yield self.env.timeout(random.randint(1, 3))
            self.order_id += 1
            order = Order(self.order_id, type)
            self.orders_cache.put(order)
            print(f"Order {self.orders_cache.items} generated at time {self.env.now}")

    def collect_and_add_to_records(self):
        while True:
            yield self.env.timeout(0)
            items = yield self.orders_cache.get()
            print(f"got: {items} at time {self.env.now}")
    
    def run(self):
        types = ['A', 'B']
        for type in types:
            self.env.process(self.generate_order(type))
        self.env.process(self.collect_and_add_to_records())
        self.env.run(until=10)

env = simpy.Environment()
sim = Simulation(env, 10) 
sim.run()
```

Output:

```
Order [Order(id=1, type='B')] generated at time 1
got: Order(id=1, type='B') at time 1
Order [Order(id=2, type='A')] generated at time 3
Order [Order(id=2, type='A'), Order(id=3, type='B')] generated at time 3
got: Order(id=2, type='A') at time 3
got: Order(id=3, type='B') at time 3
...
```

However, `simpy.Store.get()` seems to retrieve one item at a time, instead of a list of items. Is there a way to get these values together at each timestamp? I've tried appending it a few ways, but haven't been successful.

Expected output:

```
Order [Order(id=1, type='B')] generated at time 1
got: Order(id=1, type='B') at time 1
Order [Order(id=2, type='A')] generated at time 3
Order [Order(id=2, type='A'), Order(id=3, type='B')] generated at time 3
got: [Order(id=2, type='A'), Order(id=3, type='B')] at time 3
...
```

Comment: looks like you start 4 generate processes each executing self.records[self.env.now] = {}, so the last generate process executed will overwrite what the 3 other generate processes did.

Comment: @Michael, I am not sure how to work around it. I have to have those orders generated asynchronously, but also add them all to the record at each timestamp.

To uncomplicate things, I've edited the question and removed the SortedDict complexity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you have done something like

```
if key not in aDict:
  aDict[key] = []

aDict[key].append(order)
```

Comment: here is a link to a realpython article on missing keys https://realpython.com/python-defaultdict/

Comment: Yes this worked for me! specifically the dict key/value structure where key = `self.env.now` is required to access the multiple orders arriving in parallel at each timestamp. Salut @Michael !